# Generate API docs via code comments

Tags: node.js, rest, documentation, apiblueprint

I'm using aglio to generate my API documentation.  I'm currently writing the raw markdown for this based on the API Blueprint spec.  I'm wondering if there's a way to generate the markdown via comments directly in the code.  Is anyone aware of a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically it is possible. Depending on your language and used frameworks. For example, in Ruby, one could use [RSpec to generate API Blueprint](https://github.com/playround/rspec_api_blueprint).

I am not familiar with any tool that does something similar for Node.js (e.g. using Express.js DSL).

When writing a tool that is generating a blueprint, one can avoid authoring the blueprint manually and use [Matter Compiler](https://github.com/apiaryio/matter_compiler) instead. This tool (Ruby gem) converts JSON or in memory tree (AST) into API Blueprint.

Note that I personally advice against generating documentation from the code. Instead I consider API Blueprint as a contract that can be used to [test your API implementation](http://blog.apiary.io/2013/10/17/How-to-test-api-with-api-blueprint-and-dredd/).

In this sense generating a blueprint from the code is like generating tests from the code (to test the very same code).

Comment: Is it Possible to Generate  API Docs via code comments using API blueprint for java language..

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the agilo, but other alternate solution is to generate the API documentation using maven site plugin.

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <version>${maven-site-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <locales>en,fr</locales>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

You can write the apt file which contains the details of the API and later you can run maven to generate the doc. It generates the nice doc. Which is very popular and many people in industry using extensively.

More details at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html